# Do I need to escape text/plain or text/javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, security, xss

Suppose I have something like this:

```
if ($command === 'txt') {
    header('Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');
    echo $result;
    exit();
} else ($command === 'js') {
    $json = array( $result );
    header('Content-type: text/javascript;charset=utf-8');
    echo $callback . '(' . substr(json_encode($json), 1, -1) . ');';
    exit();
}
```

Can I use `htmlspecialchars` on the echo statements, it messes it up if it's interpret as html, on the other hand does not having them leave the risk that someone may try doing an xss attack if the browser does interpret it as html.

What should I do? Should I not worry and not `htmlspecialchars`?

Comment: Anyone that uses so kwality a browser that it interprets plain text as HTML has no excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should not use `htmlspecialchars`.  Neither of those would make sense, since `htmlspecialchars` is intended to avoid HTML injection.  However, if you use JSON, your client code needs to take care how it uses the returned value.

For instance, injecting it into `innerHTML` would not be safe.